# how to get the suffix value from xml structure?

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, xml-parsing, xml-serialization

I stored the xml structure in xml string like abcd variable.test1,test2,test3 are parts of the xml sructure.how to **get suffix values like 1,2,3 from test1,test2,test3**?

```
  string abcd="<xmlstruct>
    <test1>
        <name>testname1</name>
        <address>testaddress1</address>
        <subject>testsub1<subject>
    </test1>

    <test2>
        <name>testname2</name>
        <address>testaddress2</address>
        <subject>testsub2<subject>
    </test2>

    <test3>
        <name>testname3</name>
        <address>testaddress3</address>
        <subject>testsub3<subject>
    </test3>


    </xmlstruct>";
```

Comment: You meant to get value "1", "2" and "3" from test1, test2 and test3?

Comment: @CuongLe yes i need 1,2,3 values

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, don't structure your XML like that in the first place. It's not a good use of element names. It would be better to use:

```
<test id="1">
    ...
</test>

<test id="2">
   ...
</test>
```

If these are the result of having separate variables in your original classes, that suggests the variables should probably be a single collection instead.

If you *really* want to find them though, you could use something like this:

```
IEnumerable<string> ListSuffixes(XElement container, XName prefix)
{
    string localPrefix = prefix.Name.LocalName;
    var elements = container.Elements()
                            .Where(x => x.Name.Namespace == prefix.Name.Namespace
                                        && x.Name.LocalName
                                                 .StartsWith(localPrefix));
    foreach (var element in elements)
    {
        yield return element.Name.LocalName.Substring(localPrefix.Length);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve, but this isn't really how XML is normally used.

To obtain the suffixes (1, 2, 3) from a piece of XML that looks like the above then you could parse the XML, select all children of the `xmlstruct` element and then use string manipulation.

However an alternative schema would probably be a better idea, like storing the suffixes separately as attributes

```
<xmlstruct>
    <test Suffix="1">
        <name>testname1</name>
        <address>testaddress1</address>
        <subject>testsub1<subject>
    </test>
    <test Suffix="2">
        <name>testname2</name>
        <address>testaddress2</address>
        <subject>testsub2<subject>
    </test>
    <test Suffix="3">
        <name>testname3</name>
        <address>testaddress3</address>
        <subject>testsub3<subject>
    </test>
</xmlstruct>
```

Element names shouldn't really be dynamic, the list of allowed element names for a given element should normally belong to a fixed (finite) list

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
Integer.parseInt(s.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""))
```

This will also remove non-digits inbetween digits, so "test1test1x" becomes 11.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
var suffices =
    XDocument
        .Parse(abcd)
        .Element("xmlstruct")
        .Elements()
        .Where(xe => xe.Name.ToString().StartsWith("test"))
        .Select(xe => int.Parse(xe.Name.ToString().Substring(4)));
```

It returns:

[image: Results]

Comment: @user1632157 - I had to fix your xml as it wasn't valid.